# Meteor - nested each helper populated by wrapAsync call not rendering

Tags: meteor

I'm having an issue where the parent #each generates an inner #each with a wrapped async call. The server call returns the expected input and the array "thumbUrls" is correctly generated each time as shown via console.log(). However, when returned as a helper it does not exist in the template. I've tried doing this with futures, and the same thing happens.

**Template**

```
<template name="adminThumbnail">
  {{#each video}}
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-md-12'>
      <h3>{{artist}} - {{title}}</h3>

        <!-- NOT BEING RENDERED AT ALL -->
        {{#each thumbUrls}}
         <img src={{this}}>
        {{/each}}

      </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

**Client**

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
  Template.adminThumbnail.helpers({
    'video': function () {
      return Videos.find({});
    },
  'thumbUrls': function () {
     Meteor.call('listThumbnails', this.keys.prefix, function (err, data) {
       var thumbUrls = [];
       data.Contents.forEach(function (item) {
         thumbUrls.push(Meteor.settings.public.CLOUDFRONT_URL + item.Key);
       });
       /* ARRAY IS BEING GENERATED CORRECTLY */
       console.log(thumbUrls); 
       return thumbUrls;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

**Server**

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
   listThumbnails: function (prefix, cb) {
     var params = {
     Bucket: Meteor.settings.AWS.BUCKET_NAME,
     Prefix: prefix + 'thumb'
   }
   var s3 = new AWS.S3();
   var listObjectsSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(s3.listObjects, s3);
   try {
     return listObjectsSync(params);
   } catch (e) {
   console.error(e);
   }
  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your thumbUrls helper isn't returning anything. The return you are calling is the return of the callback function of the `call`, not of the helper function. And you also can't just return anything from the helper at that point, because you are in an async branch.

Use a `Session` variable instead:

```js
Session.setDefault('thumbUrls', []);
if (Meteor.isClient){
    Template.adminThumbnail.helpers({
        'video': function () {
            return Videos.find({});
        },
        'thumbUrls': function () {               
            return Session.get('thumbUrls');
        }
    });


    Meteor.startup(function() {
            Meteor.call('listThumbnails', this.keys.prefix, function (err, data) {
                var thumbUrls = [];
                data.Contents.forEach(function (item) {
                    thumbUrls.push(Meteor.settings.public.CLOUDFRONT_URL + item.Key);
                });
                /* ARRAY IS BEING GENERATED CORRECTLY */
                console.log(thumbUrls); 
                Session.set('thumbUrls', thumbUrls);
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: Christian, what is actually happening is that ALL the urls are being set to a single set of urls. Every video has its own unique set of urls. On the page itself it flashes every second and warps through all the unique urls. Really weird stuff.

Comment: I've edited the code. Maybe this is better? It's probably best to make the method call only once. I'm assuming it's OK to make it on startup.